# How does lazy loading pattern helps improve performance?

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

Lets say I have set lazy="true", and I am trying to retrieve child records for an Employee (Employee being parent, and FamilyMember being its child)

My code proceeds to build a collection of all the child records:

```
List<FamilyMember> familyMembers = new ArrayList<FamilyMember>();
Query query = session.createQuery("From FamilyMembers ...");
Iterator<FamilyMember> it = query.iterate();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    familyMembers.add(it.next());
}
```

The above iteration just builds a collection of "proxy" objects (say -list of 5 FamilyMember objects), as I understand. My question is - even to build the collection it needs to know the size of results (AND also the key field values of the child records for further use while actually fetching child records from proxy) that would be returned by some query (which it get by evidently hitting the DB), how does hibernate helps in saving performance overhead?

Further, assume some code which gets the physical record:

```
FamilyMember member = familyMembers.get(2);
```

Which FamilyMember object should the above line get? Does this imply that some implicit mapping with the key field for FamilyMember takes place behind the scene? If yes, then how come this improves performance when we are actually hitting the table for getting the related keys? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mahesh : you have attempted to edit my answer to give response.  However it should be done by commenting in my answer.  If you want to discuss on it, please provide comment so I will respond to you.  Here is your message in edit, for your reference:

Comment: - Agree, selecting family member does not actually fetch child record (accessing property of child record does), but my question is - how does Hibernate know the child record ID in order to fetch a proper record (say, using familyMembers.get(2)). Want to confirm on this- whether Hibernate stores the ID info also as part of the proxy object (to be used later when actually fetching physical record whenever attempt to retrieve any child property is made). If so, it means that while fetching parent record, it must have also queried &

Comment: got the metadata for the children (like, size of children, their IDs, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading applies on the collections/objects present in the entity where lazy loading has been applied usually via a join annotation.

For eg if your Employee class is as below:

```
class Employee{
.......
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<FamilyMember> familyList;
.......
}
```

If you fetch the Employee entity via hibernate the `familyList` is only filled with data if you try to access its data or explicitly call `hibernate.initialize` on it. This makes the query to fetch multiple Employees faster as it does not load all the FamilyMember lists asaociated with each of them.

You can read more about it at:
[Hibernate lazy loading](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading)

Answer (score 0):

So what you mean is, you have `Employee` and it has ~ToMany relationship (which is lazy fetched) to `FamilyMember`.  You have code that is iterating all family members of employee(s) right?

i.e. something like this:

```
class Employee {
    @OneToMany(fetch=LAZY)
    List<FamilyMember> familyMembers;
}
```

and in your code:

```
for (Employee employee: someEmployees) {
    for (FamilyMember member: employee.getFamilyMembrs()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

something like that? (Coz in your code example, you are simply selecting `FamilyMember` which has nothing to do with lazy fetching)

If it is the case, Lazy Fetch is NOT going to improve performance.

The main situation Lazy Fetch is helping in performance is that, the lazy-fetched relationship is not being used.  So when Hibernate is constructing the entity, it just put a proxy as the relationship, without actually retrieving the related entities, hence saving DB access, data transfer and object construction.

However in your case, you need to access the relationship, hence Hibernate won't save you from the above work.  And, given lazy fetch is done lazily, which means, your main entity will be retrieved first, and then the relationship will be retrieved when you access it.  It is usually even slower compared to a proper join-fetch to fetch the main entity + relationship all at once.

---

Update: For your extra question on: How Hibernate dealing with such kind of lazy fetching without first querying child records.  Here is what's happening in high level:

First, hibernate deal with lazy fetch differently for different kind of relationship type.  In this case, it is a `OneToMany` relationship.  What Hibernate knows, based on the mapping of: `@OneToMany List<FamilyMember> familyMembers;` is:

`FamilyMember` table (the "to many" side") is going to have a column (let's assume it named `EmployeeId` by default), containing ID of current entity (`Employee`, the "one to" side)

Hence, the lazy-fetch proxy that Hibernate is going to create is: a collection proxy, when it is accessed, will query with a SQL `select * from FamilyMember where EmployeeId = :id` for which `:id` will be provided with current entity's ID.

By doing so, when you construct the `Employee`, you do not need to query anything of its child records (`FamilyMember`).

When you, let's say, do `employee.getFamilyMembers().get(2);`, the `.get(...)` method will trigger the lazy-fetching collection proxy to populate the data, which will fetch ALL the related `FamilyMember` records (instead of only the 3rd one), and populate the collection with data, and then return you with the 3rd one.

To understand the fetching behavior of Hibernate, I'd advise you to turn on logging for SQL issued by Hibernate (by tools like jdbcdslog or log4jdbc etc), and you could visualize when and what is queried by Hibernate in situation.